# Add multiple attributes in shortcode : wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I need to convert a core php script to wordpress plugin with shortcodes so non-technicle people can also perform same task easily using the shortcodes. 
In script, there are lots of functions and each function has many attributes so I am not able to understand how to do that part correctly.

```
$pdocrud = new PDOCrud();
$pdocrud->fieldTypes("about_yourself", "textarea");//change about_yourself 'textarea' to input type text
$pdocrud->fieldTypes("gender", "radio");//change gender to radio button
$pdocrud->fieldDataBinding("gender", array("male","female"), "", "","array");//add data for radio button
$pdocrud->fieldTypes("hobbies", "checkbox");//change hobbies to checkbox button
$pdocrud->fieldDataBinding("hobbies", array("Dance","Art","Games"), "", "","array");//add data for checkbox button
$pdocrud->fieldTypes("state", "select");//change state to select dropdown
$pdocrud->fieldDataBinding("state", array("Andhra Pradesh","Bihar","Patna","Gujarat","Madhya Pradesh"), "", "","array");//add data using array in select dropdown
$pdocrud->fieldTypes("country", "multiselect");//change country to multiselect dropdown
$pdocrud->fieldDataBinding("country", array("India","Brazil","UK","Pakistan"), "", "","array");//add data using array in multiselect
echo $pdocrud->dbTable("users")->render("insertform");
```

[Here](http://pdocrud.com/demo/pages) you can find more details about the script. Only thing I need to do is to convert the script functions in
wordpress shortcode. I am able to do it using only eval function but since it is not secure so please suggest some better way. Please note that object of class
is used here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can tell the best option for you would be to use this plugin: [Wordpress Types Toolset](https://wp-types.com/)